# reading machinekey from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, antiforgerytoken, machinekey

I have a asp.net mvc web application which runs in a farm (multiple web servers). Currently we store the machine Key in the webconfig of the web app   
But I have to move this in the database (in encrypted form) for security and compliance proposes…
Is there is any way to store decryptionKey and validationKey in some secure db and provide it to asp.net at runtime? 
If not then what options I have (is there is any way to save this in some secure location in encrypted form and make asp.net to read it at runtime)?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypting Web.Config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075245/encrypting-web-config)

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18478929/296861), it might be possible to read machine key from database at run-time.